# circuitikz: three phase generator

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I'm trying to draw a simple ac/dc converter schematics with `circuitikz`. My attempt gives the following result:

[image]

I would like to have instead of the three sinusoidal current generators a single three-phase sinusoidal current generator with three branches going out of it. How would this be possible?

The code for my attempt is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
% Generator side
\draw
    (5,1) to [vsourcesin, i_=$i_c$] (8,1)
    (5,2.5) to [vsourcesin, -*,i_=$i_b$] (8,2.5)
    (5,4) to [vsourcesin, i_=$i_a$] (8,4)
    (8,1) to [short] (8,2.5)
    (8,4) to [short] (8,2.5);
% Converter
\draw
    (3.5,0.5) -- (5,4.5) (3.5,0.5) rectangle (5,4.5);
\path
    (3.5,4.5)+(.3,-.3) node{DC}
    (5.0,0.5)+(-.3,.3) node{AC};
% DC-Link
\draw
    (3.5,4) to [short, i_=$i_{\mathrm{up}}$] (2,4)
    (3.5,1) to [short, i_=$i_{\mathrm{low}}$] (2,1)
    (3.5,2.5) to [short,-*, i_=$i_{\mathrm{np}}$] (2,2.5)
    (0.5,2.5) to [short] (2,2.5)
    (0.5,1) to [short] (2,1)
    (0.5,4) to [short] (2,4)
    (2,1) to [C=$C_{\mathrm{low}}$](2,2.5)
    (2,2.5) to [C=$C_{\mathrm{up}}$](2,4);
% Grid
\draw (-1,0.5) rectangle (0.5,4.5);
\path (-0.25,2.5) node[rotate=90] (grid) {Grid};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you add a sketch of what you would like to have, I could help (when I find time... tomorrow, maybe). Meanwhile maybe  https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZYp9.png can help? (Manual, page 75, "Source borders").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *guess* you want something like this?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
    % Generator side
    \begin{scope}[xshift=-4cm, color=red]
        \draw
        (5,1) to [vsourcesin, i_=$i_c$] (8,1)
        (5,2.5) to [vsourcesin, -*,i_=$i_b$] (8,2.5)
        (5,4) to [vsourcesin, i_=$i_a$] (8,4)
        (8,1) to [short] (8,2.5)
        (8,4) to [short] (8,2.5);
    \end{scope}
    %
    \draw
    (5,1) to [short, i<_=$i_c$] (6,1) coordinate(fc)
    (5,2.5) to [short, ,i<_=$i_b$] (6,2.5) coordinate(fb)
    (5,4) to [short, i<_=$i_a$] (6,4) coordinate(fa)
    (8,1) to [short, -*] (8,2.5) coordinate(common) to [short] (8,4)
    (common) to[vsourcesin, name=myv] (fb)
    ($(myv.center)!1!60:(myv.right)$) -- (fc)
    ($(myv.center)!1!-60:(myv.right)$) -- (fa)
    ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]